# Issue working with Timemanager plugin of qgis

Tags: qgis, import-from-csv

I am trying to create an animation layer using a CSV file, but the layer appears blank with small "time frame size".

Attached images have sample data I am plotting with 'hour4' as the time field.

[image: sample data]

[image: creating settings]

The layer appears blank until I select 'Time Frame Size' as 1 year. Ideally it should work with 'Time Frame Size' = '1 day' as my data is at date level with date ranging from 2016-08-08 till 2016-08-23.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Please show us some lines of your input CSV data in text format..